# EWS extended property not present in email when replied from mobile device

Tags: exchangewebservices

Hi I am writing an application that adds an extended property to an email sent using EWS; when the user replies from Outlook the extended property is present and my application can read the property.

My issue is when the user replies the email from a mobile device, the extended property is not present anymore.

**Here is the code that I use to add the property:**

```
 Exchange.EmailMessage email = new Exchange.EmailMessage(_ExchangeService);
 email.ToRecipients.Add(txtEmailAddress.Text);
 email.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
 email.Body = txtBody.Text;
 Guid MyPropertySetId = new Guid("{C11FF724-AA03-4555-9952-8FA248A11C3E}");
 Exchange.ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition = new Exchange.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MyPropertySetId, "ValidationId", Exchange.MapiPropertyType.String);
 email.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, "234");
 email.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

**And the following is the code to read the property:**

```
Guid MyPropertySetId = new Guid("{C11FF724-AA03-4555-9952-8FA248A11C3E}");

Exchange.ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition = new Exchange.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MyPropertySetId, "ValidationId", Exchange.MapiPropertyType.String);

Exchange.ItemView view = new Exchange.ItemView(10);
Exchange.PropertySet properties = new Exchange.PropertySet(Exchange.BasePropertySet.IdOnly, Exchange.ItemSchema.Subject, extendedPropertyDefinition);
properties.RequestedBodyType = Exchange.BodyType.Text;
properties.BasePropertySet = BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties;
foreach (Exchange.EmailMessage item in emails)
{
   item.Load(properties);
   if (item.IsRead)
   {
      continue;
   }

   if (item.ExtendedProperties.Count > 0)
   {
     foreach (Exchange.ExtendedProperty extendedProperty in item.ExtendedProperties)
     {
       if (extendedProperty.PropertyDefinition.Name == "ValidationId")
       {
         txtPropertyNameReceived.Text = extendedProperty.PropertyDefinition.Name;
         txtPropertyValueReceived.Text = extendedProperty.Value.ToString();

       }
       else
       {
         continue;
       }
     }
     item.Delete(Exchange.DeleteMode.HardDelete);
   }
}
```

Is this issue expected? I mean, is this happening because the user is replying from his phone? Or is there something wrong in the code?

If the issue is the code may I ask for your help to tell me what part is missing or wrong in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an explanation why it does not work:

1. When a person replies, this action creates a new copy of an email
2. That means as an Email Client App (or plugin) developer you need to manually copy extended properties from original message to the new one
3. Extended properties are MAPI properties, which can be discovered using Microsoft's MAPI proprietary protocol
4. I'm not aware of any MAPI client library for mobile devices (except Windows powered devices)